# WIX CustomAction C#

Tags: c, wix

please tell me what to write in this line in parentheses

```
var UtilityKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(...);
```

**This is the code of CustomAction:**

```
public static ActionResult ConfigUpgrade(Session session)
        {
            var UtilityKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(...);
    if (UtilityKey != null)
            {
                var value = UtilityKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion");
                session.Log("Utility installation found! Version: {0}", value);
                session["UTILITYINSTALLATIONEXISTS"] = "1";
            }
            else
            {
                session.Log("Utility installation not found!");
                session["UTILITYINSTALLATIONEXISTS"] = "0";
             }   

           return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Really nobody can answer this simple question?

Comment: You're supposed to pass in the name of the subkey that you're looking for, but I don't know how anyone but you can know what that subkey is. What is the subkey that you're expecting to find the `DisplayVersion` value in? I think it might be the GUID of your application, if this is related to what you're trying to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: I always get an error:   Error 2 The command "..." exited with code 1. Can you help me?

Comment: Usually : keyPath = @"SOFTWARE\MyApp\Settings";                                             What is it? Help me please

Comment: So are you saying you've done this before with some other app and it has worked? If so, you most likely know a lot more than I do about this. But if not, where are you seeing that error? Is it appearing when you run the installer and it reaches the custom action? I don't have WiX tools around me right now, but at a guess I'd say that's happening because your custom action is throwing an exception. Do you see any of your `session.Log` messages in the installation log file? Or does the installation not get that far through the custom action?

Comment: This error occurs when I compile and did not even get to Build a solution

Comment: A quick Google on that error comes up with results about pre- or post- build events. Do you have any of those set up?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found a suitable solution to Google for this error. I just do not understand what it means variable UtilityKey. So I can not understand what it should contain and because of what the error

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Maybe you know some article that describes a solution to this error?                                               I also have a second error recompile:                                     Error 1 No CA or UI entry points found in module: ....

Comment: I think that your code shouldn't be the problem at this point, it sounds like your problems are all with building your solution and you should first work on fixing that. I'm sorry, I don't know any articles that will help you, maybe someone else will be able to but I think you'll first need to give some more information about the project you're working on and the other files you have. For your second error I searched Google and found some references to the same error when people were trying to use something called "Embedded UI" in order to have a custom installer UI. Are you trying to do this?

Comment: No, I do not use the "Embedded UI".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adam Goodwin said in the comments, you need to enter the path to the registry key you are looking for, but there is no need to use a Custom Action for this

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/read_a_registry_entry.html

How To: Read a Registry Entry During Installation

Installers often need to look up the value of a registry entry during the installation process. The resulting registry value is often used in a conditional statement later in install, such as to install a specific component if a registry entry is not found. This how to demonstrates reading an integer value from the registry and verifying that it exists in a launch condition.
Step 1: Read the registry entry into a property

Registry entries are read using the  element. The following snippet looks for the the presence of the key that identifies the installation of .NET Framework 2.0 on the target machine*.

```
<Property Id="NETFRAMEWORK20">
    <RegistrySearch
                Id="NetFramework20"
                Root="HKLM"
                Key="Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727"
                Name="Install"
                Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

The RegistrySearch element specifies a unique id, the root in the registry to search, and the key to look under. The name attribute specifies the specific value to query. The type attribute specifies how the value should be treated. Raw indicates that the value should be prefixed according to the data type of the value. In this case, since Install is a DWORD, the resulting value will be prepended with a #.

The above sample will set the NETFRAMEWORK20 property to "#1" if the registry key was found, and to nothing if it wasn't.
Step 2: Use the property in a condition

After the property is set you can use it in a condition anywhere in your WiX project. The following snippet demonstrates how to use it to block installation if .NET Framework 2.0 is not installed.

```
<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 2.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK20]]>
</Condition>
```

Installed is a Windows Installer property that ensures the check is only done when the user is installing the application, rather than on a repair or remove. The NETFRAMEWORK20 part of the condition will pass if the property was set. If it is not set the installer will display the error message then abort the installation process.

- This registry entry is used for sample purposes only. If you want to detect the installed version of .NET Framework you can use the built-in WiX support. For more information see How To: Check for .NET Framework Versions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. This is similar to what I need. 
My problem: if you use 2 version of the product, then update the file, if you use version 3, then leave the file without updating.

Comment: I corrected my mistakes. Thank you, Your example has pushed me to the right decision.

Comment: No problem, usually if your task involves Microsoft technology, especially if it's not a new feature, then WiX or an extension will already have an idiomatic way to achieve it.